# Which method i need to use?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the data table:

[image]

And i have the choose table:

[image]

I need some code, that can  sum value by  (for example :

if cells in  choose table is not empty, then sum values from rows, where direction = 'East' and city = 'NY' and month = 10. (return 1)

If cells direction and month is empty, then sum values from rows,where  city = 'NY' . return (4).

And etc...

If cells in  choose table is empty, then sum values without limitation. (return 15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a `SUMIFS` formula. There is no need for VBA.

I'm going to assume the 'Choose' table is on another sheet in your real world, but the formula works if it's on the same sheet - I just wouldn't do it that way due to potential circular references if columns overlap.

Formula:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,IF(B10="","*",B10),B:B,IF(B11="","*",B11),C:C,IF(B12="",">0",B12))
```

Basically, it replaces empty entries with a wildcard (where it's text) and with `">0"` where the column is numerical. Tweak as you see fit.